# Copying the text from Web Inspector in safari using AppleScript

Tags: safari, applescript

I have to copy and paste the code from Safari's web inspector. For now, the code I am using is:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set frontmost to true
        click menu item "Show Web Inspector" of menu "Develop" of menu bar 1
        --      click menu item "Select All" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Copy" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1
        delay 1
    end tell

end tell

set desktopPath to (path to desktop as text)

tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    set newDoc to (make new document with properties {text:(the clipboard)})
    save newDoc in file (desktopPath & (name of newDoc) & ".html")
end tell
```

But the problem with this code is, instead of copying the content from web inspector, it's copying the text content from the page. Or in some cases, the clipboard isn't getting modified. How can I get the job done?

PS. I am a beginner ;D

Comment: I'd place some adequate `delay` _commands_ between the _events_. This way the **Web Inspector** has time to open and have focus to be copied. But why not just save the page as `Format: Page Source`?

Comment: Yes, I could save the page source directly. But, the goal is to solve this problem as for preparation of an exam. :)

Comment: Okay, I typically do not help users with their homework however, while the first time  Web Inspector opens to the Elements tab it nonetheless typically opens to the last tab selected, so you may need to take that into consideration too.

Answer (score -2):

To solve your problem, I would use Keyboard maestro, instead of doing the 'edit>select all' I would tell keyboard maestro to press "Cmd+A"

Comment: It is sometimes appropriate to include clarifying questions about the OP’s requirements as part of a more comprehensive answer. But you definitely should not include new questions as part of an answer. Instead, propose an answer and then, if you can’t find a solution to your own problem on Stack Overflow, post it as a new question.